# ng-hide by checking browser url in view angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ui-router

```
<div class="panel"ng-controller="DashboardPartnerCtrl as vm">
    <div class="panel-body">


            <li ui-sref="app.partners.detail({id:partner._id})" ng-repeat="partner in vm.partners">
                <span class="partnerHead">{{partner.name}}</span>

            </li>


         <div ui-view></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the `li` when the url changed to `app/partners/123`, how to use ng-hide in this case?

Answer (score 0):

First, in your `DashboardPartnerCtrl` controller, inject the `$location` service and place a boolean flag :

```
angular.module('amodule').controller('DashboardPartnerCtrl', ['$location', '$scope', 
    function($location, $scope){
        $scope.hideLiElement = ($location.path() === 'app/partners/123');
}]);
```

Then, in your HTML part :

```
<li ng-hide="hideLiElement" ui-sref="app.partners.detail({id:partner._id})" ng-repeat="partner in vm.partners">
    <span class="partnerHead">{{partner.name}}</span>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to hide the li of the partner that is selected in your state.

In this case the easies way to hide the li is to use `ui-sref-active` [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active). You can use it like ng-class. It will apply the classes you provide to the element where the ui-sref matches the current state. Just define a class that sets display to none and your are done.

Otherwise you have to inject $location to your controller and assign it to a variable in order to use it in the template. You may use a function where you input the id and it returns a boolean you can pluck into your ng-hide.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ui-sref-active` directive to apply a class when `li` is `active` but here you want exact opposite condition. So just provide `hidden` class there in directive.

```
<li ng-repeat="partner in vm.partners" ui-sref-active="hidden">
  <a ui-sref="app.partners.detail({id:partner._id})"> 
    <span class="partnerHead">{{partner.name}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hmm can I don't use an `a`?

Comment: why you don't want `a` tag there?

Comment: @JessicaIlly did you get a time to check it?